# How to track the resolution/aspect ratio of a WebRTC remote VideoStream?

Tags: android, webrtc-android

I have develop an android application which implement native WebRTC for video chat and i would like to present the remote video resolution and other video information but i was not able to find an WebRTC API for android that is providing this information.

I know that in javascript, there is the **MediaStreamTrack.getSettings()** API. the question is, how can i get the same information as MediaStreamTrack.getSettings() in **Android, JAVA?**

Comment: Are you using a webrtc library or similar? How are you implementing the functionality currently?

Comment: Are you using Socket.io or WebSockets? Why you don't use them to send and sync those datas between clients before starting call?

Comment: i am using my Web Socket and i  know what data i am sending but this is not my question. my question is how do i know what each side receiving? for that i need to be able to get it from the remote video track but i did not find any way to get such kind of data.

Comment: for the first comment, yes, i am using Native Android WEBRTC library with JAVA websocket.as a signaling server and XIRSYS STUN & TURN servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 years I have back to my old question and now I was able to get the actual remote video resolution.

Here are the details for other people may need it:

```
private EglBase rootEglBase = EglBase.create();
private EglBase.Context eglBaseContext = rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext();
private SurfaceViewRenderer fullScreenView = findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        fullScreenView.init(eglBaseContext, new RendererCommon.RendererEvents() {
        @Override
        public void onFirstFrameRendered() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameResolutionChanged(int videoWidth, int videoHeight, int rotation) {
            Log.i("ZCF", "onFrameResolutionChanged: W=" + videoWidth + "H=" + videoHeight + " rotation:" + rotation);
        }
    });
```

;